# Is the tags section valid in the info.yml file?

Tags: 8, .info

I see in the [devel.info.yml](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/devel/blob/8.x-2.x/devel.info.yml) file a section named tags

```
tags:
- developer
```

But I can't find it on [the documentation page](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/let-drupal-8-know-about-your-module-with-an-infoyml-file). Is the tags section valid in the info.yml file or is it just an error?

Comment: You can add whatever you like to the yml file, so it wouldn't be a question of "valid" or an "error" as such. Just a matter of what (if anything) consumes that data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not think it is valid yet. There is an issue on this

https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1868444